# Convert df column to a tuple

Tags: dataframe, zip, tuples, tolist

I am having trouble converting a df column into a tuple that I can iterate through. I started with a simple code that works like this:

```
 set= 'pare-10040137', 'pare-10034330', 'pare-00022936', 'pare-10025987', 'pare-10036617'

 for i in set:

     ref_data=req_data[req_data['REQ_NUM']==i]
```

This works fine, but now I want my set to come from a df. The df looks like this:

```
 open_reqs

Out[233]: 
          REQ_NUM
4825  pare-00023728
4826  pare-00023773 
.... ..............
```

I want all of those `REQ_NUM` values thrown into a tuple, so I tried to do `open_reqs.apply(tuple, axis=1)` and `tuple(zip(open_reqs.columns,open_reqs.T.values.tolist()))` but it's not able to iterate through either of these.

My old set looks like this, so this is the format I need to match to iterate through like I was before. I'm not sure if the `Unicode` is also an issue (when I print above I get  (u'pare-10052173',)

```
 In[236]: set
 Out[236]: 
 ('pare-10040137',
  'pare-10034330',
  'pare-00022936',
  'pare-10025987',
  'pare-10036617')
```

So basically I need the magic code to get a nice simple set like that from the REQ_NUM column of my open_reqs table. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

The following statement makes a list out of the specified column and then converts it to an array of tuple

```
open_req_list = tuple(list(open_reqs['REQ_NUM']))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tolist() function to convert to a list and the tuple() the whole list

```
req_num = tuple(open_reqs['REQ_NUM'].tolist())
#type(req_num)
req_num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

columns_tuple = tuple(df.columns)
```

`df.columns` has the datatype of object. To convert it into tuples, use this code and you will GET TUPLE OF ALL COLUMN NAMES